# How to default a nested defaultdict() to a list of specified length?

Tags: python, dictionary, defaultdict

I'd like to know how to default a nested defaultdict to a list `[0,0,0]`. For example, I'd like to make this hierarchical defaultdict.

```
dic01 = {'year2017': {'jul_to_sep_temperature':[25, 20, 17], 
                      'oct_to_dec_temperature':[10,  8,  7]},
         'year2018': {'jan_to_mar_temperature':[ 8,  9, 10].
                      'apr_to_jun_temperature':[ 0,  0,  0]}
        }
```

To make this nested dictioanry, I did `dic01 = defaultdict(dict)` and added a dictionary as `dic01['year2018']['jan_temperature'] = [8, 9, 10]`. My question is if it's possible to update each element of a list without previously binding [0, 0, 0]. In other works, if I make a defaultdict as `defaultdict(dict)`, I have to bind a list [0,0,0] before using it, and I'd like to skip this binding process.

```
# The way I do this
dic01['year2018']['jul_to_sep_temperature'] = [0,0,0]    # -> how to omit this procedure?
dic01['year2018']['jul_to_sep_temperature'][0] = 25

# The way I want to do this
dic01['year2018']['jul_to_sep_temperature'][0] = 25      # by the end of July
```

Comment: If you omit the initialization procedure, then how will Python know that the list is supposed to have 3 elements?

Comment: @Parag S. Chandakkar I'm sorry. Maybe my question was not clear. I meant that if I could set a default list when making a dictioanry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify that you want a default value of a `defaultdict` that has a default value of `[0, 0, 0]`

```
from collections import defaultdict

dic01 = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: [0, 0, 0]))

dic01['year2018']['jul_to_sep_temperature'][0] = 25

print(dic01)
```

prints

```
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x7f4dc28ac598>, {'year2018': defaultdict(<function <lambda>.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7f4dc28ac510>, {'jul_to_sep_temperature': [25, 0, 0]})})
```

Which you can treat as a regular nested dictionary

Comment: Thank you for youranswer! It's more simpler than the way I do it. Do you happen to know if it will be more efficient and use less resources compared to the way I do, when repeated million times?

Comment: @maynull I don't know how they relate in terms of efficiency.  I suspect the `defaultdict` solution will be slightly slower, and take more memory.  I don't know enough to say whether or not that difference will be meaningful.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is more elegant than what you are trying to avoid, but:

```
dic01 = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: [0,0,0]))
dic01['year2018']['jul_to_sep_temperature'][0] = 25
```

you can nest `defaultdicts` however you want by passing lambda functions

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It looks clearer than the way I do.